# Does Ruach Ra'ah transfer between people

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

If one washes netilays yadaim in the morning and thus eliminates their ruach ra'ah and then someone who has not yet washed their hands touches you do you have to wash again?

Answer (score 4):

Per Rabbi Ovadya Yosef Zatzal one would have to wash again if he touches the hands of one who did not wash yet.

> מי שנטל ידיו שחרית, וחזר ונגע בידיו של מי שלא נטל ידיו שחרית, חוזר
>   ונוטל ידיו, אף אם נגע בידי חברו כשידיו יבשות.

http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2
4:15

Answer (score 3):

Rivevos Ephraim 8:7:1 writes that he searched and did not find anyone who rules on this.He writes that it seems that one does not have to rewash ,but it is good to be machmir and wash again without a bracha.