# Question on the transfer of Ruach Ra'ah

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, hands-fingers

I've heard ( do not have a source ) that if you don't wash right after waking up, the Ruach Ra'ah transfers itself to all objects you touch. Does this object become tumei? How is it removed from the object? Meaning if I touch my phone before washing, and wash and then touch again, does that tumei get transferred to my hands, making me need to wash again before davening or saying a bracha, learning Torah? How would a object become clean if this is the case?

Comment: ruach ra is not tumah.

Comment: Fine, then the transfer of tumah in the same situation.

Comment: betzalel, I don't understand your comment. I want to make sure you get answers that will address what you're asking. Are you asking about _ruach raa_ or about _tum'a_?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34305/759

Comment: @doubleaa ,see Mishna Brurah siman 4 where it talks about a non Jew is not mekabel tumah,so it seems ruach rah do have some sort of tumah aspect but obviously it is different ,and the effect it has on food.