# Touching the hands of a Jew who didn't wash netilat yadayim in the morning

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing

When one has performed netilat yadayim in the morning, however after their hands are **dry**, touched or shook the hands of ***a Jew*** who ***hasn't*** washed their hands, but their hands are ***also dry***, would they need to wash again?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34305/does-ruach-raah-transfer-between-people

Comment: most people wash themselves in the shower and wash their hands which would likely minimally satisfy the requirement for netilas yadayim. It would be really uncommon in today's society to find people who do not wash their hands at all.

Comment: Mikayah just a friendly reminder to not neglect going through old questions and seeing if any answer can be "accepted", as you haven't accepted any answers on the site yet :) Click here to see an overview of your questions https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/28939/mikayah-yisrael?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the כף החיים, the שו"ת לב חיים (ח"א סימן ס"ה) and the בו איש חי (תולדות י"ב) also say that if one touches someone's hands that didn't wash his hands, one should wash his/her own hands again.

But the פסקי תשובות (בימן ד” י"א) writes that this chumra is not found in other mainstream Poskim. Although a ירא שמים might want to be מחמיר to follow the חומרא.

Answer (score 3):

Caf Hachayim OC 2.4 SQ 17

> (יז) מי שנטל ידיו, ואחר כך נגע בידיו של אחר שלא נטל ידיו, צריך לחזור וליטול פעם ב'. רוח חיים שם אות ו', וכן כתב בן איש חי שם אות י"ב בשם לב חיים סימן ס"ה. ‏

> One who has washed his hands and then has touched the hands of someone who has not washed them, must start again a second time, Ruach Chayim letter Vav (6).  It is also written in the Ben Ish Chay letter You'd Bet (12) in the name of Lev Chayim Siman 65.

Comment: I believe this applies while one's hands are still wet, not once they are dry

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the netilat yadayim laseuda @Esther

Comment: I'm referring to dry hands for both individuals.

Comment: I am also referring to this @MikayahYisrael